# Updating source of frame at runtime in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

We have a WPF application which use frame to show a page. This page has a single TextBlock named "myTextBlock" in it. We set source of frame programmatically as following:

```
myFrame.Source = new Uri("sourceOfPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

We want to change text of myTextBlock at runtime.

```
 public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    ......

    public Page1(string textToBeShown)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.myTextBlock.Text = textToBeShown;
    }
}
```

Because we don't initialize Page programmatically we can't send any text to Page (Page must display text depends on condition). We tried:

```
Page1 myPage = new Page1("Hello");
myFrame.Source = myPage; // It doesn't work
```

So how can we pass parameter to page and display it in frame? Is it possible? If it is, how can we achive that?

**Note:** My workmate created new static class. This static class has string property. Then he sets value of this property and shows it in page. It solved the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry I did not really understand what you want. You can post a bit more code or talk about the problem?

Comment: well. i guess if you switch over to the MVVM pattern (which suits great for most WPF related stuff), your problem would be gone.  your textblock has a binding to some property on your datacontext. change the property (using INotifyPropertyChanged) and the rest works out of the box.